# Facebook Login for "Different" Domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook, koala

I am using rails 3.1 with Koala. I am aware that facebook lets you add multiple domains when setting up an app where each of the domain name has to be derived from the site url, so if site url is myapp.com, you can have domains like myapp.co.uk, myapp.jp and myapp.somedomain.com but What if the domain names are completely different and since they are all a part of a single application (where each domain name refers to a different section of the app - very much like how themeforest.net audiojungle.net do it) they require a single authentication and single facebook login.

Right now, when I enter these different domain names, facebook does not accept them. I need these different domains as each domain caters to a different market but uses the exact same software and needs to be linked together so that user attributes can be shared between these markets.

Does anyone know how to make a single fb-app accept these different domain names for logging in users to this single web app.